# SpriteKit Physics - Nodes not staying in bounds of screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Simple code below creates a ball (on touch) and set physics body to make it fall and bounce. I set the bounds to match the frame, wanting the ball to remain 100% within the screen. However when running the code, the ball will move off the screen out of view left and right. How can I keep the sprite within the bounds of the screen?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
            ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.4
            ball.position = location
            addChild(ball)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your scene size, and your view size ... By default, scene is loaded from .sks file, and its dimensions are 1024x768.

Comment: Printing out the fame size shows...Frame: 768.0, 1024.0, same as SKS file

Comment: That is the scene size. That is what I said in my previous comment. But what is the view's (an SKView) size ? Print inside scene `self.view?.bounds.size`... You probably want something like this in your GameViewController : `scene.size = skView.bounds.size`

Comment: Better, but doesn't work when rotating the device.